# Why would outputting a [PSCustomObject] change execution order

Tags: powershell, output

Why, in the second pair of commands, is Read-Host processed before the object is output?

```
PS > (1..3).ForEach{ @{ a=$_ } }; Read-Host 'pause1'
Name                           Value                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                          
a                              1                                                                                                              
a                              2                                                                                                              
a                              3                                                                                                              
pause1: 

PS > (1..3).ForEach{ [PSCustomObject]@{ a=$_ } }; Read-Host 'pause2'
pause2: 
a
-
1
2
3
```

I would have affirmed that this just started happening. A script that output a [PSCustomObject] must now complete before the output is seen. Entering the debugger after the loop but before the script's completion means the output is not seen.

Comment: The execution order isn't changed but the items in the pipeline are hold till the command line is finnished before they being released to the default output (which is the display). You might force them to be displayed by using the specific [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) cmdlet: `(1..3).ForEach{ [PSCustomObject]@{ a=$_ } } |Write-Host; Read-Host 'pause2'`

Comment: OK, so it is not execution order, but your answer doesn't solve the issue, which is that the object is not being outputted to the host, or explain why the behavior is different when the object is a simple hashtable. Also, What if it was a foreach loop that does not support piping ForEach($i in (1..3)){ [PSCustomObject]@{ a=$_ } } |Write-Host; Read-Host 'pause2'? What if you had a breakpoint inside the loop and wished to see each object prior to the entire loop's completion?

Answer (score 0):

The execution order isn't changed but the items in the pipeline are hold till the command sequence is finished before they being released to the default output ([which is the display](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output#description)).

#### Prove

1. Enter a response to `Read-Host 'pause2'` cmdlet and note that the response is added at the end of the pipeline:

```
pause2: Test
a
-
1
2
3
Test
```

2. Add some timestamps to the testing:

```
(1..3).ForEach{ [PSCustomObject]@{ a=(Get-Date).ToString('HH:mm:ss.fffffff') } } ; Read-Host (Get-Date).ToString('HH:mm:ss.fffffff')
15:41:29.1931049:
a
-
15:41:29.1916159
15:41:29.1918194
15:41:29.1919053
```

#### Solution

Explicitly force the pipeline items to be immediately displayed by using the specific [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) cmdlet:

```
(1..3).ForEach{ [PSCustomObject]@{ a=$_ } } |Write-Host; Read-Host 'pause2'
@{a=1}
@{a=2}
@{a=3}
pause2:
```

Comment: OK, so it is not execution order, but your solution doesn't solve the issue, which is that the object is not being outputted to the host. What if it was a foreach loop that does not support piping ```ForEach($i in (1..3)){ [PSCustomObject]@{ a=$_ } } |Write-Host; Read-Host 'pause2'```? What if you had a breakpoint inside the loop and wished to see each object prior to the entire loop's completion? Nor do you explain why the behavior is different when the object is a simple hashtable.