# How to prevent executing next line, unless the current line is executed?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to output list of samaccountname and description first, then scan names for ACL.

The problem is the script jumps to scanning ACL first, then print list of samaccountname and description

Code:

```
cd C:\;

. .\PowerView.ps1;

Write-Output "Users:";
$Users = Get-DomainUser -UACFilter NOT_ACCOUNTDISABLE;
$Users | Select-Object -Property samaccountname, description;
Write-Output "=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=";
Write-Output ""

Write-Output "ACL:";
$Users | select -ExpandProperty name;
$UsersArray = @();
$UsersArray += $Users;
foreach ($user in $UsersArray) {
    Invoke-ACLScanner -ResolveGUIDs | ?{($_.IdentityReference -match "$user") -or ($_.IdentityReferenceName -match "$user")};
}
```

Comment: Tables tend to come out slower.  Format-table runs in the background and there's a delay until 2 objects come out.  Just output one table in your script, or try piping individual lines to format-table or format-list, etc.

Comment: Why are you performing `$UsersArray += $Users`? Just do `$UsersArray = @($Users)`, or even better `$Users = @(Get-DomainUser -UACFIlter NOT_ACCOUNTDISABLE)` and just iterate over `$Users` directly. `+=` will create a *copy* of the array in memory , which while `@()` has no elements that would be copied this way, you are still creating a copy of your returned AD information.  IDK how many users you expect to return but this could be a costly operation. Just iterate over `$Users`.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why would outputting a PSCustomObject change execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68713328/1701026)?